# Cross-staff chord in score with multiple voices in Lilypond

Tags: notation, software, lilypond

Assume I need to reproduce the following piano music.  Notice the middle "voice" spans both staves.  How would I accomplish this using Lilypond?

(I am aware of a hack involving adjusting the stem length, but I would prefer solutions that will not break if the distance between staves were to change.)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How's this?

```
\version "2.19.45"

global = {
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
}

right = \relative c'' {
  \global

  <<
    {
      \override NoteColumn.force-hshift = -0.5 <d f>8 q q q %% remove the override to see the difference!
    }
    \\
    {
      \crossStaff { \stemUp g,2 }
    }
  >>
}

left = \relative c' {
  \global

  <<
    {
      \crossStaff { b2 }
    }
    \\
    {
      <g, d'>4 q
    }
  >>
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "right" \right
    \new Staff = "left" { \clef bass \left }
  >>
  \layout {
  \context {
    \PianoStaff
    \consists #Span_stem_engraver
  }}
}
```

This gives precisely:

[image]

Basically, you just need to include the `Span_stem_engraver` context and then provide the cross-staff pitches within `\crossStaff` brackets.

You'll notice that I inserted `\override NoteColumn.force-hshift = -0.5` before the opening `<d f>` eighth notes in the right hand; without this, the right hand stems conflict:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, including the `Span_stem_engraver` context is critical.  That was the missing bit I needed in order to get `\crossStaff` to work.

Comment: The 2.18.2 release of LilyPond fails to respect the `NoteColumn.force-hshift` tweak, so stems will still conflict.  However, this example works just fine in the given dev version, 2.19.45.